# Symfony doctrine entity insert error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I really strange have problem with inserting entity

in foreach use this code :

```
public function setGate($keyId, $elementId, $keywordType){

    echo "<BR>setGate $keyId , $elementId";
    if(!intval($keyId) or !intval($elementId))
        throw new MeaException("$keyId,$elementId Keywords setGate empty");

    $gate = $this->repositoryGate
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e.id')
            ->where('e.mkeywords_id=:keyid and e.elid=:elid')
            ->setParameters(array('keyid'=>$keyId,'elid'=>$elementId))
            ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if($gate) return true;

    $gateObj = new KeywordsGate();

    $gateObj->setElid($elementId);
    $gateObj->setMkeywordsId($keyId);
    $gateObj->setMkeywordstypeId($keywordType);

    $this->em->persist($gateObj);

    try {
        $this->em->flush();
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        var_dump($gateObj);
        var_dump($e);
        die('e');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

on each i echo numbers :

```
echo "<BR>setGate $keyId , $elementId";
```

have :

```
setGate 1558 , 5922
setGate 1348 , 5922
....
setGate 1474 , 5922
setGate 1475 , 5922
setGate 1476 , 5922
```

and on one element have error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'mkeywords_id' cannot be null'
```

and have in screen:

```
object(Miejsce\KeywordsBundle\Entity\KeywordsGate)[1206]
  private 'id' => null
  private 'mkeywords_id' => int 1476
  private 'elid' => string '5922' (length=4)
  private 'mkeywordstype_id' => int 4
  private 'keywordElement' => null

object(Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException)[1208]
  protected 'message' => string 'An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO mKeywordsGate (mkeywords_id, elid, mkeywordstype_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "5922", 4]:
```

so where can by a error ?

Comment: Please fix your code:  `$this->em->persist($gateObj)` instead of  `$this->em->persist($gateObj`

Comment: i fixed - off corse i make this error when i paste to stackoverflow

Comment: Could you post the full foreach code?

Comment: mkeywords_id is a foreign key column right? if its foreign key then you have to insert its entity on      $gateObj->setMkeywordsId($keyIdEntity);

Comment: Yes you have right - when i put object and  $gateObj->setKeywordElement($keywordObject); not $gateObj->setMkeywordsId(integer $keyId); script work fine.